# Finding a gem from the require line in code

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I currently have an installer that installs a set of ruby scripts (that is an optional install from the main program).  I have written a script that after the install, it scans through all of the require statements inside the contained ruby files, and then pulls out all of the "required" files.  For example, it will look for

```
require 'curb'
require 'rest-client'
# require etc...
```

that is in each file, and then include them in a list (removing duplicates) so I have an array that looks like:

```
"curb", "rest-client", etc...
```

For most gems its perfectly fine, as the names match, and I just do a

```
gem install GEMNAME
```

In the case that the names do not match however, I am trying to figure out a way to find out the gem name from the require line, by querying the gem server.  For example:

xml-simple has a require statement of xmlsimple, but the gem is xml-simple.  After much searching, the only "solution" that I can find is to install every gem and check to see if the files are contained inside with the

```
gem specification GEMNAME
```

This is far from optimal, and actually a really bad idea, and I was wondering if there was a way to query rubygems to see what files are contained inside of a gem.

Answer (score 0):

Rubygems has an [API](http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-org-api/) with a search endpoint:

```
/api/v1/search.(json|xml|yaml)?query=[YOUR QUERY]
```

The search endpoint is listed at [Gem Methods](http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-org-api/#gem). I'm sure this search can be used to do what you want, perhaps by providing a partial name and using a regex to filter for the closes matches.

Edit: 
It may also be work having a look at the [Bundler](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler) gem itself, as they sometimes recommend gems when you make a typo if I remember correctly.

Update:

I would follow a workflow like this:

Try to install gems just are they are required.

If there is an error select a few segments of the gemname, say `gem_name_str[0..5]`, `gem_name_str[0..4]` and `gem_name_str[0..3]`.

Query the API with these strings.

Remove duplicates

Test the values returned with a dynamically generated regex. Something like:

```
#given @param name = string from 'require' statement

values_returned_from_api.each do |value|
  split_name = name.split(//)
  split_value = value.split(//)
  high_mark = 0

  #this will find the index of the last character which is the same in both strings
  for (i in 0..split_name.length) do
    if split_name[i] == split_value[i]
      high_mark = i
    else
      break
    end
  end

  #this regex will tell you if the names differ by only one character
  #at the point where they stopped matching. In my experience, this has
  #been the only way gem names differ from their require statement.
  #such as 'active_record'/'activerecord', 'xml-simple'/'xmlsimple' etc...

  #get the shorter name of the two
  regex_str = split_name.length < split_value.length ? split_name : split_value

  #get the longer name of the two
  comparison_str = split_name.length < split_value.length ? value : name

  #build the regex
  regex_str.insert((high_mark + 1), '.')  #insert a dot where the two strings differ
  regex = /#{regex_str.join('')}/

  return name if comparison_str =~ regex
end
```

Note: this code is not tested. Its just to illustrate the point. It can also probably be optimized and condensed.

I am assuming that the API returns partial matches. I haven't actually tried it out.

Comment: The only problem I see from the search API is that you still have to provide a gem name.  There is also no way to see what is contained in the gemfiles from that search as well.

Comment: Given a partial gemname, you should get back a list of potential matches. You can then use a regex to scan these for the most likely candidate. See the updated answer for more.